# How to insert dynamically some attributes in a XML tag with Ruby Builder?

Tags: ruby, xml, builder

I'm generating XML file dynamiquely from database using Ruby Builder (http://builder.rubyforge.org/).

To add a Tag which name is in a variable, I found this: 
xml.tag!(@myTagName)

How to dynamiquelly insert à list of attributes in this Tag ?

- I dont know the names of the attributes which are loaded dynamically from database
- I need to create a loop because I dont know how many attributes will be inserted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it shouldn't be hard to do what you need. Whenever you add a tag you can pass along an optional hash which will be the tag's attributes. So for example if you do:

```
  builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
  xml = builder.person(name: "foo", age: 0 )
```

Then you will get `<person name='foo' age='0'/>`

So in a similar way if you build your dynamic attributes as a hash you can use the `#tag!` method like the following:

```
xml = builder.tag!(tag_name, attributes_hash)
```